# Split one row into multiple rows in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the attached screenshot. I'm trying to figure out how we can achieve that using SQL Server.

[image: [Data Transformation Requirement]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVKyHm.png)

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact logic?

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Looks like you want to create a bunch of recurring, monthly appointments based on a single -- dialog box's worth of input maybe? Unless this is part of a school assignment, I'd strongly suggest you work with the data as is and allow your program's business logic to infer the subsequent dates. If not for any other reason, but updates and deletes will become nightmarish from a coding standpoint.

Comment: Is this to be the result of a SELECT, or do you want to UPDATE the data in the table permanently?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using recursive CTE,

For Ex : (I assumed your date column is in MM/DD/YYYY format)

```
;with orig_src as
(
    select CAST('01/01/2018' AS DATETIME) As Dt, 'Alpha' Name, 3 Freq
    UNION ALL
    select CAST('12/01/2018' AS DATETIME) As Dt, 'Beta' Name, 2 Freq
), freq_cte as
(
    --start/anchor row
    select dt, name, 1 freq_new, Freq rn from orig_src  
    --recursion
    union all
    select DATEADD(MONTH, 1, a.dt), a.name, 1 freq_new, a.rn - 1 from freq_cte a
    --terminator/constraint for recursion
    where  a.rn - 1 ! = 0
)
select convert(varchar, dt, 101) dt, name, freq_new from freq_cte
order by 2,1
```

The way this recursive logic works is,
First we get all the rows from the table in a CTE (freq_cte), then we recursively call this CTE and decrement rn (original freq) till the terminator condition is met that is when (rn -1) = 0